# Heavy App size after including ScoutMap framework

Tags: skmaps

On questioning the size of the app in development. my developer tells me that the size of the Scout Map Framework itself is 140MB which is adding to the size of the overall app.

I am not very convinced as I don't believe your own app is that large so it's a bit improbable as no one would use Scout Maps if it was that heavy.

Are we missing a trick somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the demo provided from SKMaps version 3.0 includes offline region to be shown. You need to extract from assets folder. It will reduce the size if you do not want to bundle up with offline feature.